# Call Function within a function in R

Tags: r, function, loops

I have a function readTochens which is to read csv files. I want to loop through a few more files. the following is the code and it doesn't work. Error message is that No Such file or direction. Any suggestions?

```
dir <- c("allfac12","allfac13")
cpas <- c("cpas12","cpas13")

mainloop <- function(){
  for(i in 1:length(dir)){
  readTochens(as.name(dir[i]),as.name(cpas[i]))
  }
}
mainloop()
```

Comment: Is `readTochens()` from a package? or did you write it yourself? Either provide the package this function came from or the code you used to define it.

Comment: What is your working directory?  Where in the file system do directories do ```allfac12``` and ```allfac13``` live?  Are the files ```cpas12``` and ```cpas13``` in the right place?  Do you need an extension (like .csv)?

Comment: hmm, are you in the right directory? you can do `getwd()` to check